# Running script on remote server and provide run time argument to stop execution

Tags: python

I was working on a Python script which will do the following task:

1. Run a script on remote server with comand line arguments. The script is already there on remote machine.

   Script execution format: `python sameple.py read_config.cfg MyLogs`
2. Upon running the script it will wait for some user input. The user input is to stop the script.

   ```
   python sameple.py read_config.cfg MyLogs

   Type anything to stop the execution : ________
   ```
3. Once we type anything it will start stopping the script. Stopping may take some time as well.

How can I proceed with it using Python modules?

Comment: Is the user input 100% necessary? If not, you can start scripts with `cron` and remotely stop them using `cron` + `ssh`.

Comment: Yes User Input for stopping the script is neccesary. Either we have to press Control + C or give some input and hit enter to stop the script.

Comment: Why? You could define an alias where it executes `kill -9 $(pidof python)`.

Comment: Are you going to ssh into the remote to start and stop the program? Have you looked at tmux and what it might do for you? What work have you accomplished so far? Are you using the `threading` package?